# Grant [almost] all mySQL privileges for all but one/a few tables

Tags: mysql, database

## Question:

How can I give a new user almost all privileges, but still keep one or more tables/databases protected from them.

## Details:

If I have one database,

- `life`

And three tables

- `passwords`
- `friends`
- `hobbies`

How do I give this user, for example, the following privileges:

- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE
- CREATE
- DROP
- ALTER

With respect to the first three, I would start with something like so:

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON life.friends TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON life.hobbies TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

But I am confused as to how to use `CREATE` and `DROP`. If I grant drop privileges on the whole database like so:

```
GRANT DROP ON life TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then the user can drop the `passwords` table, which I do not want. I could instead grant it based on tables like so:

```
GRANT DROP ON life.friends TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT DROP ON life.hobbies TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

But then what happens if I grant `CREATE` privileges like so:

```
GRANT CREATE ON life TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Does that mean that the user can not even delete the very tables he/she creates? My question also relates to creating/dropping databases. What if I want to allow the user to create and drop as many of **their own** databases, but **not** the `life` database?

Should I instead change my approach by moving the `passwords` table into another database?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Separate databases are the way to go. MySql permissions are limited. They do not allow `deny` privileges.

Comment: @TheScrumMeister I'll accept that as an answer if you post it

Comment: its not a full answer ;-). As someone who has dealt with MySql permissions, this is one of the (many) limitations i came across.

Comment: Were you able to gain any traction on this?

Comment: @MikePurcell somewhat. I am using separate databases for `CREATE/DROP` permissions, using `GRANT` to give users access to specific columns, and `VIEWS` to give users access only to specific rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to @TheScrumMeister's suggestion of using separate databases would be to define a procedure that wraps `CREATE TABLE`, but also grants the invoking user the `DROP` permission on it:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE create_table(
  tbl_name VARCHAR(64) -- maximum length of a table name
) BEGIN
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
  START TRANSACTION;
    SET @usr = SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(), '@', 1);  -- invoking username
    SET @tbl = REPLACE(tbl_name, "`", "``");     -- prevent SQL injection

    -- just create some dummy table initially - the user can modify it after
    SET @qry = CONCAT("
      CREATE TABLE `", @tbl, "` (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
      );
    ");
    PREPARE stmt FROM  @qry;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    -- now grant DROP to the invoking user but only from localhost
    SET @qry = CONCAT("
      GRANT DROP ON life.`", @tbl, "`
      TO CONCAT(?, \"@'localhost'\") IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
    ");
    PREPARE stmt FROM  @qry;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @usr;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    -- clean up
    SET @qry = NULL;
    SET @usr = NULL;
  COMMIT;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

To be certain that the user doesn't create tables any other way, they should not have the `CREATE TABLE` privilege.

You could do something similar for databases too.

Comment: I never thought of that. Thanks